# $\lim_{x\to0}e^{-1/x^2}$ and complex limits

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

I was wondering about the following limit, when I realized something that should be fundamentally wrong.

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}e^{-1/x^2} & =\lim_{u\to\infty}e^{-u^2}\tag{$x^+=x^-$} \\
& =0
\end{align}$$

What I saw to be fundamentally wrong is that the limit only considered $x$ as it approached zero from the positive and negative side, but it fails to consider the limit approaching $0$ from any complex direction.

For example: (I may not be doing it correctly, but try to envision that I am changing the direction the limit approaches $0$ in the complex plane)

$$\lim_{x\to0}e^{-1/(ix)^2}=\lim_{x\to0}e^{1/x^2}=+\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}e^{-1/\left[(1+i)x\right]^2}=\lim_{x\to0}e^{i/2x^2}=\text{DNE}$$

the last limit is bounded, but does not converge to any value and instead oscillates.

And so, I sort of come to the conclusion that $\lim_{x\to0}e^{-1/x^2}$ only converges if it is approached from $x^+$ and $x^-$.  (I have the assumption that we usually don't discuss such things in a normal calculus setting and that such thoughts would only come around complex analysis)

Comment: Yup. $e^{-1/z^2}$ has no limit as $z \to 0$ in the complex plane (not even $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ - the limit literally doesn't exist. This is an example of an [essential singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity)). But depending upon context (say eg in calculus) you should interpret $\lim_{x \to 0} e^{-1/x^2}$ as a real limit (so approach from $0^+$ and $0^-$).